# Bibliography not showing up

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am having an issue with my .bib file. Both in text references and the bibliography at the end do not show up. These are the error messages I get:

```
The top-level auxiliary file: Chapter_one_26.02.21.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Chapter_one_26.02.21.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Chapter_one_26.02.21.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Chapter_one_26.02.21.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

and this is my code:

```
...
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BiblioC1.bib}
...
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

any ideas of why this is happening?
Thanks a lot

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) exactly which program did you run here? It looks like you ran `bibtex`, but `biblatex` expects `biber` unless stated otherwise

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the bibliography is exported from Zotero so I guess it is a bibtex file. Should I use a different package?

Comment: You're confusing things here. You bibliographical data is in a format called `bibtex`-format. This can be handled via several different external programmes to produce the bibliography that latex can then typeset. The primary of those programmes are called `bibtex` and `biber` (yes the programme has the same name as the data format, like like with latex). So we need to know exactly which external program you are using here to handle the conversion from the `.bib` file to latex

Comment: I see, thanks. I am not sure of what external programme I am using but if I use `natbib` instead of  `biblatex` it seems to work so I guess it is bibtex, correct?

Comment: Correct, but `biblatex` will work fine, you just need to tell your editor to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`. How to do that depends on the editor.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 has step-by-step instructions to set up the most common editors for Biber. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains in more detail what Biber and BibTeX do and why they need to be run on your file.