# File not compiling after changing bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I was working on a .tex file but as soon as I changed the .bib file it stopped working and it does not compile the file anymore. I am sure they are both in the same folder and I already used the same .bib file for other version of the paper. I am using Tex Studio and this is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
...
%bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
...
\begin{document}
...
%bibliography
\bibliography{BiblioC1}
...
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to delete the generated bbl and then compile again,sometimes it does not update the bibliography. Also, could you specify which error do you get?

Comment: If you configured your editor to run Biber for you for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585380/35864, you may need to tell your editor to run BibTeX again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have managed to fix it.